# Is there IDE support for pkg-config

Tags: redhawksdr

Is there any pkg-config support in the IDE?

If not, how do I add a build variable to the compile and another to the link using the IDE?

Or, how do a pass custom compiler / linker options?

Answer (score 0):

The IDE does not have any UI elements for adding pkg-config requirements. However, you can and should directly edit your project's configure.ac for these using the standard autoconf macros for pkg-config (see [man 1 pkg-config](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config)).

For example, in your configure.ac replace the line that looks like this:

`PKG_CHECK_MODULES([PROJECTDEPS], [ossie >= 1.8 omniORB4 >= 4.0.0])`

With something like this:

`PKG_CHECK_MODULES([PROJECTDEPS], [ossie >= 1.8 omniORB4 >= 4.0.0 mylibfoo >= 1.0.0])`